# POSTGRESQL multiple select, multiple row arrays possible?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, select, array-agg

Say I'm doing something simple like selecting everything from two tables:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2;"
```

It will return a results object that looks like:

```
{rows:[{},{},{} etc...]}
```

Where the array of row objects is every row from `table1`, followed by every row from `table2`.

What I want is to be able to combine the above `SELECT` statements into one DB query but have it return something like:

```
[
{table1rows:[{},{},{}]}
,{table2rows:[{},{},{}]}
]
```

...so that I can avoid multiple queries of the DB while then fudging each query's results object into a custom object I reference from DB query to DB query like a caveman. So one query, one clean results set I can handle on the client knowing which array of rows came from which table.

Can you use `AS` for this? How would I achieve this with one query?

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL` to combine the results of two selects. But selecting every column and row from two tables doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: I'm not going to select all rows in reality, but for ease of reading I left that part out...

Comment: You also left out which part of the food chain formats the output as JSON array, because Postgres does not do that for a plain `SELECT`. You can make Postgres output JSON, but then your unnamed piece of software will nest that another time.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to:
   - use **[combine multiple queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-union.html)** with `UNION ALL`;
   - build `json` array with  [`json_build_object`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) and `json_agg` functions;

Example `SELECT` can be the following:

```
WITH table1(a1,b1) AS ( VALUES
  ('valA1','valB1')
), table2(a2,b2) AS ( VALUES
  ('valA2','valB2')
)
SELECT json_agg(each_table_rows.data) FROM (
  SELECT json_build_object('table1rows',tbl1.*) AS data
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
  ) tbl1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT json_build_object('table2rows',tbl2.*)
  FROM (
    SELECT t2.* FROM table2 t2
  ) tbl2
) each_table_rows;
```

Result:

```
                                           json_agg                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"table1rows" : {"a1":"valA1","b1":"valB1"}}, {"table2rows" : {"a2":"valA2","b2":"valB2"}}]
(1 row)
```